# Greasemonkey to inject Adfly ads

Tags: javascript, browser, greasemonkey, userscripts

Is there any way to convert this into Greasemonkey code?

```
<script>
var adfly_id = 517450;
var adfly_advert = 'banner';
var frequency_cap = 5;
var frequency_delay = 5;
var init_delay = 3;
</script>
<script src="http://adf.ly/js/entry.js"></script>
```

It's a website entry script for adf.ly which when added to a website brings up adf.ly ads.

I want to make a script that will load adf.ly links in the browser while surfing.

Please help!
Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in theory. You'd just need to write these to the head. They will evaluate outside of the greasemonkey scope if you load them on the page direction. you can even just do a `document.body.appendChild` after creating script tags. So,

```
var sc = document.createElement('script');
sc.src = "http://adf.ly/js/entry.js"
document.body.appendChild(sc);
```

For the other one, it'd probably just be easier to do an `unsafeWindow.varname` assignment like

```
unsafeWindow.adfly_id = 517450;
unsafeWindow.adfly_advert = 'banner';
unsafeWindow.frequency_cap = 5;
unsafeWindow.frequency_delay = 5;
unsafeWindow.init_delay = 3;
```

Though you don't ever want to use these values in your script, as these can be changed by the website itself. Using them gives websites access to more control over a users browser and lets them do things that they would not otherwise be able to do (for example, accessing information from other websites via XSS ajax). Only write to values in unsafeWindow, don't read from them.

Comment: Edit your answer to show *how* `unsafeWindow` would be used (plus the warning), and I'll upvote.

Comment: I added it, though I think yours is a good solution, and you are right that it would port to chrome, so that's certainly a bonus of my method.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to inject the JS into the page.  [Avoid `unsafeWindow` if you can](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow).

Here's a complete Greasemonkey translation of that script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            _adFly why?
// @include         http://YOUR_SITE/YOUR_PATH/*
// ==/UserScript==


function myCode () {
    //--- Set global variables for adFly.
    window.adfly_id         = 517450;
    window.adfly_advert     = 'banner';
    window.frequency_cap    = 5;
    window.frequency_delay  = 5;
    window.init_delay       = 3;
}

addJS_Node (null, null, myCode);
addJS_Node (null, "http://adf.ly/js/entry.js");

function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun) {
    var D                                   = document;
    var scriptNode                          = D.createElement ('script');
    scriptNode.type                         = "text/javascript";
    if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
    if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
    if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';

    var targ    = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}
```

Comment: I agree to avoid it, but since he is just writing properties, and not reading from them, I considered it an okay thing. I should, however, have linked to the article so that at least the risks were outlined... +1

Comment: Yes, the dangers are exaggerated, practically speaking (but still real).  In this case, since script injection was needed anyway, there's no need for even that small risk. Plus this approach ports to Chrome with no additional modification.